# Game Center achievements for Cat Physics

Tags: achievements, game-center

Since a major update a few days ago, Cat Physics (and other Donut Games games like Cave Bowling) supported Game Center features and achievements. When I look at my Game Center account now, I can see I've earned 11 out of 12 achievements, but if I take a look at the list, there are only 11 achievements listed (and I've gotten all of them) - nothing I haven't earned and nothing that is in progress. The achievements I've earned:

- 2500 points
- 15000 points
- 50000 points
- Completed 10
- Completed 40
- Completed 90
- Three-starred 10
- Three-starred 50
- Fifty Buttons
- Fifty slingshots
- Fifty teleporters

What's the missing achievement and why isn't it listed in Game Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist. They're saving it for the next update.

http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=55864&page=955

Congrats on all those achievements though.

Answer (score 1):

to update this with a definite answer: with the last update to Cat Physics, 10 new challenges and the 12th achievement were introduced.

One can get that achievement for getting 3 stars in 100 challenges (which means 3 stars in *all* challenges as there are only 100).